# Why is nothing showing up in my Java GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, awt

I am currently working on a calculator. Right now, I am trying to gain experience with coding Java GUI, by making a simple program that makes a window with a text field. The code can compile without errors, but when I execute the program, the window appears, but without the text field. How do I make the text field visible? The code is shown as follows:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Window {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame Window = new JFrame("Window");
        Window.setSize(400,550);
    Window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel Panel = new JPanel (new FlowLayout());
    JTextField TextField = new JTextField("Type something here");
    Window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to add the `JTextField` to the panel, and the panel to the `JFrame`.

Comment: just write panel.add(TextField); then add(panel);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't added any of the components to your JFrame. You can add them like so:

```
Panel.add(TextField);
Window.add(Panel);
Window.setVisible(true);
```

---

**Side note:** You should stick to the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). Use camel case for variable names.

Comment: +1 but would be great if you use java naming convention in your code :)

Comment: @nachokk: I stuck with what OP had so that they could just paste the code in and run. It's up to OP to decide whether or not they want to change the names or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the components that you have instantiated (e.g. the `Panel` and `TextField`) and add them to appropriate containers.

For example:

```
Panel.add(TextField);
Window.add(Panel);
```

If you have not done so already, I would highly recommend visiting http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html  for more information on how to use the Swing library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add them before making the frame visible.

```
Panel.add(TextField);
Window.add(Panel);
```