# Nothing Displayed On Screen Java Swing Application

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SimultaneousSolver extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

    JTextField  tfEQ1X  = new JTextField (20);
    JTextField  tfEQ1Y  = new JTextField (20);
    JTextField  tfEQ1Num    = new JTextField (20);

    JTextField  tfEQ2X  = new JTextField (20);
    JTextField  tfEQ2Y  = new JTextField (20);
    JTextField  tfEQ2Num    = new JTextField (20);

    JLabel lblX1 = new JLabel ("X₁");
    JLabel lblY1 = new JLabel ("Y₁");
    JLabel lblNum1  = new JLabel ("Number₁");
    JLabel lblEqual1 = new JLabel ("=");

    JLabel lblX2 = new JLabel ("X₂");
    JLabel lblY2 = new JLabel ("Y₂");
    JLabel lblNum2  = new JLabel ("Number₂");
    JLabel lblEqual2 = new JLabel ("=");

    JTextArea Empty = new JTextArea ("",1,20);

    double X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Num1, Num2;
    double SolX, SolY;

    Font font = new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 14);

    SimultaneousSolver()
    {
        super ("Simultaneous Equation Solver");
        setDesign();
        setSize(700,400);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panelEquation1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,7));
        {
            panelEquation1.add(lblX1);
            panelEquation1.add(tfEQ1X);
            panelEquation1.add(lblY1);
            panelEquation1.add(tfEQ1Y);
            panelEquation1.add(lblEqual1);
            panelEquation1.add(lblNum1);
            panelEquation1.add(tfEQ1Num);
        }

        JPanel panelEquation2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,7));
        {
            panelEquation2.add(lblX2);
            panelEquation2.add(tfEQ2X);
            panelEquation2.add(lblY2);
            panelEquation2.add(tfEQ2Y);
            panelEquation2.add(lblEqual2);
            panelEquation2.add(lblNum2);
            panelEquation2.add(tfEQ2Num);
        }

        setVisible(true);
    }


    public final void setDesign() 
    {
        try 
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        }   
        catch(Exception e) 
        {   
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new SimultaneousSolver();
    }

}
```

Ok, So I am starting a new application development using pure swing if possible, so i set up my objects and stuff and when I try to run the application to see if it looks good, Nothing Shows up except an empty container.[image: Screenshot of the app when run]

Comment: where did you add these new jpanel instances to the main window (frame) ?

Comment: you need to add the panels into the frame....

Comment: so I need to initialize JPanels like i did the JTextField and stuff?
It doesn't work like in AWT?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22030127/why-is-nothing-showing-up-in-my-java-gui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these two lines at the end of constructor.

```
setLayout(new GridLayout());  // sets layout for frame - you can choose any one suitable layout
add(panelEquation1);  // adds 1st panel
add(panelEquation2); // adds 2nd panel
```

Comment: Can you guess why this won't work? i.e only the second panel will be shown ;-)

Comment: specify and set a layout for your main jframe. Now the one panel hides the another.

Comment: You should also not that the default layout for JFrame is BorderLayout. That said, when you `add(component)` without specifying a `BorderLayout.[POSITION]`, the component gets automatically added the `BorderLayout.CENTER`, last man wins. That's why with the pre-edited answer, only the second panel would show - the second kicked out the first.

Comment: I'll remember that peeskillet. Thanks for helping out a JAVA Noob